# What is this diagram shown during Dragon docking with the ISS?

Tags: iss, docking, dragon

While docking with the ISS, the live stream showed this diagram with a green line starting at the capsule and looping around the area of the ISS.  It would sporadically change and loop around the screen.

Some sort of relative motion indication, perhaps not relevant after docked and just showing accelerometer noise?

[image: SpaceX Dragon Capsule Docking]

Comment: It does look like an extrapolated difference in orbits over the next several Earth orbits, ignoring the mechanical connection. And not just noise: the station has active attitude control thrusters and control moment gyroscopes that were making adjustments during this process (they called out switching from thrusters to CMGs to reduce jostling while doing the hard dock).

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff They didn't go to free drift for docking? Interesting. I guess they had to for shuttle because it was so much more massive.

Comment: @OrganicMarble IIRC, the Shuttle took over attitude control duties while it was docked, and you wouldn't want the systems fighting each other. The Dragon probably inhibited its attitude control system before it made physical contact.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff The ISS had to be in free drift for docking, after that "it depends" on which took over control. But only one at a time.

Comment: Over the radio, I heard that they transferred control from the ISS to the Dragon, but I don't know the specifics of what that meant.

Comment: For reference, https://youtu.be/AIyonw6LEOs?t=23925 is one of the SpaceX stream timestamps showing this display after soft-capture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned on the livestream, the green line is the projected future trajectory of the Dragon spacecraft relative to the ISS, assuming no outside forces (eg. thruster firings).  Once Dragon is docked to the ISS, it's meaningless, as there's a rather large outside force in the form of the docking latches.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Otherwise, it's Some Guy on the Internet Saying Something.

Comment: It was mentioned on the livestream.

Comment: Editing that fact into your answer would be somewhat of an improvement.

Comment: Some guy on the ISS? Cool. :)

Comment: NASA's relative motion display on the ISS, RPOP, also showed this kind of relative trajectory after docking too.  We just didn't bother propagating it more than about 10 minutes out.  During sims on the ground it was even worse, because sims would cut data at soft-dock and RPOP would extrapolate the drift right through the ISS (no contact model in RPOP).

Comment: For reference, RPOP and the Dragon 2 Docking monitor are shown on a station feed (it was ISS downlink 6, I happen to know) on SpaceX's stream here https://youtu.be/AIyonw6LEOs?t=23669 .  I'm having trouble finding where SpaceX's relative motion display (the one depicted appears to be a different color theme for the one seen on the center monitor in the capsule) is called out as such on the livestream